# APK and Expo Client android app are different

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building a cross-platform app with expo SDK36. I am testing with the expo client on android and ios.

It seems that the built expo apk downloaded on expo is different than the android version tested from my android expo client.

I can't scroll on my views with the app APK, hopefully, I saw it.

- Is this an expo bug and is this expected? I was expecting to have the same app on both expo and real app.
- I must rebuild until I find the bug, the APK and expo pipelines are quite busy, how can I troubleshoot efficiently without ejecting?

Answer (score 0):

it is running cache. run this command. It will clear the cache.

```
npm start --cache-clear
```

Comment: I have already run this command and this will clear the cache when you run expo client in development, the issue I have is in the production apk.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your expo project on the cloud didn't update. Try

> expo publish

Comment: I am already publishing on the cloud before building with expo.